# Get the button to edit that one record?

Tags: php, mysqli

So i've been trying to get one record and edit it by pressing the button that is created in that table, but honestly, i have no idea how to do that. Dx Can anyone help me with this? (Yes, i want the button created for each record. You know, so at the end of every row in the table, every record will have it's own button.)

```
while($rArt = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
 echo '<tr><td>' . $rArt['ArtID'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $rArt['FiliaalID'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $rArt['Productnaam'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $rArt['Inkoopprijs'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $rArt['Voorraad'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $rArt['Min_voorraad'] . '</td>';
 $voo = $rArt['Voorraad'];
 $minvoo = $rArt['Min_voorraad'];
 $nodig = $minvoo * 2 - $voo;
 $chosen = $rArt['ArtID'];
 echo '<td>' . $nodig . '</td>';
 echo '<td><input type="submit" name="bestel" value="Bestel"></td></tr>';

 if(isset($_GET['bestel'])){
  $query = mysqli_query($mysql, "
   UPDATE artikel a, voorraad v
   SET v.voorraad = v.voorraad + '$nodig'
   WHERE a.artid = v.artid
   AND v.voorraad = '$chosen'");
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a button if anyway the update is not of anything from the user?!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: You could run through the edit without the button, since it looks like the update is not of any daya from the user. You UPDATE $nodig which is calculated from an array. Unless any other parts of the code are missing here

Comment: also where is the action of the form.... I could only assume it is actioned to the same page

Comment: @PalDev It is indeed.

Answer (score 0):

**Read the comment in the solution as they are important.**

```
 while($rArt = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    // echo '<tr><td>' . $rArt['ArtID'] . '</td>'; 
                //The above line i removed and added the line below
                echo '<tr><td>'  .'<a href=\'admin.php?ArtID='.$rArt['ArtID'].'\'>'.$rArt['ArtID'] .'</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $rArt['FiliaalID'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $rArt['Productnaam'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $rArt['Inkoopprijs'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $rArt['Voorraad'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $rArt['Min_voorraad'] . '</td>';
     $voo = $rArt['Voorraad'];
     $minvoo = $rArt['Min_voorraad'];
     $nodig = $minvoo * 2 - $voo;
     $chosen = $rArt['ArtID'];
     echo '<td>' . $nodig . '</td>';
     //echo '<td><input type="submit" name="bestel" value="Bestel"></td></tr>';
     //removed this as you dont need input button here.
            }///Your while loop should close here not in the ent
     if(isset($_GET['bestel'])){
      $query = mysqli_query($mysql, "
       UPDATE artikel a, voorraad v
       SET v.voorraad = v.voorraad + '$nodig'
       WHERE a.artid = v.artid
       AND v.voorraad = '$chosen'");
     }
    //} I remove this tag as your while loop should close before isset function
```

Comment: That row makes one cell at the end which says the ArtID and then Edit. For example: 4Edit.

Comment: yah than you can click and edit it na?? that what the link going to do. when ever you click on the link it will the query in the isset function. hope it help

Comment: @BigbyBoss72 yah than you can click and edit it na?? that what the link going to do. when ever you click on the link it will the query in the isset function. hope it help. if you already read it than sorry

Comment: Right now, i can't get it to work. I followed your instructions. And i press the <a href=\'yourFileName.php?bestel='.$bestel.'\'> link, but the address is now "index.php?bestel=". But there's supposed to be something there, right?

Comment: @BigbyBoss72 i did not see your comment. so your saying its empty. if its empty. can you post your query before the while loop please. because its empty cause you are not getting any value in it.

Comment: @bigbyBoss72 see the whole code in updated answer. This time i posted the whole code. and the code is working. as i checked it this time on my local machine. if it does not work. check the query before while loop or post it here. and its important if it does not work give me reply and tell me what url you are getting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use submit in this case, but just a suggestion:

Why don't you try it this way:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Artikel ID</td> 
  <td> **<a href="bestelpagina/edit/id/1">** </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So you can create an action called Edit in which you can do the changes.